# I click radio button the radio group disappears but the space will not be removed.how to remove the space?

Tags: android

If click radio button,it shows another set of radio group in same screen and again i click the same radio button the radio group disappear and the space will not be removed

Comment: user `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 0):

It must be because you are hiding them by setting the visibility to View.INVISIBLE. In order to also get rid of the space try setting the visibility to View.GONE

Answer (score 0):

use radioGroup.setVisibility(View.Gone). If you use radioGroup.setVisibility(View.Invisible) it will takes up space for layout purposes

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
radioButton.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);
```

instead of

```
radioButton.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE);
```

**Reason behind this is**

**GONE :** This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

**INVISIBLE :** This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

- ***For your references***
  [VIEW.GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) 
  [VIEW.INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)